# Deleting records in table contains 180 Million in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, oracle-sqldeveloper, sql-tuning

Friends,

I have order tables which have minimum 100 Million records in each table. We have a job running which invokes a stored procedure which deletes atleast 50K (MIN) and 200K (MAX) records per day.

I'm currently using SQL BULK COLLECT to delete records from the table. Currently it is taking more than 4 hours for deleting 50K which is dead slow.

After searching in google, Figured out CTAS method ,i,e Creating table and keeping the records which we want and drop the existing one and rename the temp table. I CANNOT DO THIS AS THIS OPTION WAS NOT ACCEPTED AS THE TABLES ARE MORE CRITICAL.

Could you please suggest some solution to improve the performance of the same?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: What are the 50K records that are deleted ? On what basis is a record selected to be deleted?

Comment: What's wrong with "delete from <table> where <condition>"? What is the bulk collect used for?

Comment: I'm using FORALL to delete. Records are being deleted based on Time Stamp.

Comment: Rene- Deleting records one by one will take more time especially table contains 180 million. Also it generates more redo and undo logs.Correct me if I'm wrong?

Comment: What is your criterion for deleting records? Do you delete the oldest ones? Have you considered partitioning?

Comment: Yes I'm considering Partition,Tom is suggesting 3 options CASE#1:
create table new_table unrecoverable as select * from old_table where ....;
drop table old_table;
rename new_table to old_table;
create index old_table_idx1 on old_table(c1,c2) unrecoverable parallel 5;
.....

NO log on that, just move the data to a new table, drop/rename old/new, create indexes as 
fast as possible without log.

CASE#2:
partition the data, do a parallel delete.  Each partition will use its own rollback 
segment, each will run in parallel.

THE OPTION LEFT TO ME IS HAVING A PARTION

Comment: 4 hours to delete 50K rows seems much too long, regardless of how the rows are deleted.  You should profile and monitor your code to see exactly where the time is spent.  Is there a bad join causing the row selection to take forever?  Does the table have dozens of indexes making the deletes very slow?

Comment: You do seem to be looking for a solution without having established what the problem really is. Unless you know why it's slow you won't be able to have any confidence that your changes will actually help, and you could end up spending a lot of time and effort for no benefit (or even make things worse).

Comment: Jonearles - 4 hours for deleting records in 50 tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the condition for deleting the records?

Maybe you can create a function based index on this table. Then you may delete the records with a single and simple delete statement. Or think about table partitioning. If your partition key is smart and covers the delete condition you can drop or purge the old partition within a few seconds.

Btw, with package `DBMS_REDEFINITION` you can change a "normal" table to a partitized table even without interruption of service.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have enough physical disk space to duplicate your data, you could use the following approach (I assume your table is called ORDERS):

- create a copy ORDER_B of your order table with `CREATE TABLE orders_b AS SELECT * FROM orders`
- rename your original table to ORDERS_A: `ALTER TABLE orders RENAME TO orders_a`
- create a synonym called ORDERS pointing to ORDERS_A: `CREATE SYNONYM orders FOR order_a`

So far, so good. Your client code now uses the synonym ORDERS instead of the physical table.
Now comes the fun part (the daily refresh routine):

- truncate ORDERS_B
- fill ORDERS_B with `INSERT /*+APPEND+*/` (you might also want to try the PARALLEL hint)
- switch the synonym ORDERS to point to ORDERS_B
- next day: repeat with ORDERS_A instead of ORDERS_B
- repeat ad infinitum

Alternatively, instead of using TRUNCATE/INSERT, you could DROP the table and re-CREATE it. This requires more work, since you'll also have to recreate indices and grants.

This technique is called synonym switching - you might want to read [Tyler Muth's article about synonym switching](https://tylermuth.wordpress.com/2010/10/11/synonym-switching-technique-and-tools/) to get a more complete explanation of it.

Comment: Frank- Indeed a great solution But,As I have mentioned in m y first post, Ive suggested the same, this is the transaction table which will be available for customer 24 X 7 and hence the suggestion was rejected

Comment: @Prabhu Using this approach, the data *will* be available 24x7

Comment: Agreed Frank, But  Business rejected this approach.

Comment: I don't think that's a suitable solution - not for such huge tables.